# escape reserved chars from a regexp(sed) parameter

Tags: regex, sed, escaping

I want to write a script that modifies a variable in a .properties file. The user enters the new value which is in turn written into the file.

```
read -p "Input Variable?" newVar
sed -r 's/^\s*myvar=.*/myvar=${newVar}/' ./config.properties
```

Unfortunately problems arise when the user inputs special characters. In my use case it is very likely that a "/" character is typed. So my guess is that I have to parse ${newVar} for all slashes and escape them? But how? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

have a look at bash `printf`

```
%q  quote the argument in a way that can be reused as shell input
```

Example:

```
$ printf "%q" "input with special characters // \\ / \ $ # @"
input\ with\ special\ characters\ //\ \\\ /\ \\\ \$\ #\ @
```

Comment: The problem here is that the shell will strip \ characters from `$newVar` before the printf command even sees it. Other than writing a custom shell loop, I don't know of any way to output/pass a shell variable containing \ characters. Even in the above example one of the two \ characters has been lost. This is a tricky one indeed. Anybody?

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding shell quoting is a good general principle.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 properties-file ..\n" unless @ARGV;

print "New value for myvar?\n";
chomp(my $new = <STDIN>);

$^I = ".bak";
while (<>) {
  s/^(\s*myvar\s*=\s*).*$/$1$new/;
  print;
}
```

Substitution with `s///` as above will be familiar to `sed` users.

The code above uses Perl's in-place editing facility (enabled most commonly with the `-i` switch but above with the special `$^I` variable) to modify files named on the command line and create backups with the `.bak` extension.

Example usage:

```
$ cat foo.properties 
theirvar=123
myvar=FIXME

$ ./prog foo.properties 
New value for myvar?
foo\bar

$ cat foo.properties
theirvar=123
myvar=foo\bar

$ cat foo.properties.bak 
theirvar=123
myvar=FIXME
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: oops, we are only qoting the value, not the regex. So this is what you need

You are better off using `perl` instead of `sed` for this if it is available.

```
read -p "Input Variable?" newVar
perl -i -p -e 'BEGIN{$val=shift;}'           \
           -e 's/^\s*myvar=.*/myvar=$val/'   \
           "$newVar" ./config.properties
```

Edit2: Sorry, still does not handle \ characters in newVar. Guess one of the other solutions is better. As stated before, dealing with shell escaping is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a tool that understands variables -- Perl, maybe AWK -- trying to quote a random string so that you avoid all unintended interactions with sed command parsing is asking for trouble.

Also, you won't get your variable interpolated when using single quotes, and even with `-r`, sed does not grok Perl regex syntax -- `-r` only gets you to the `egrep` version of regexes, so `\s` doesn't do what you want.

Anyway, ignoring my own advice, here's how we'd do it in the old days before we had those better tools:

```
read -p "Input Variable?" newVar
sed "/^ *myvar=/c\\
myvar=`echo \"$newVar\" | sed 's/\\\\/\\\\\\\\/'`" ./config.properties
```

If you don't think your users will figure out how to input literal backslashes at your prompt, you can simplify this to:

```
read -p "Input Variable?" newVar
sed "/^ *myvar=/c\\
myvar=$newVar" ./config.properties
```